# Is it possible to create a dataset from another dataset in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created 2 datasets that return data from a web service.

now I want to merge those two datasets in a single dataset, is it possible to create another dataset that contains those 2 merged ?

PS: you can also propose new solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SSRS doesn't offer that feature. One alternative is using the `Lookup` and `LookupSet` functions to use both datasets together in the report, but this is not efficient for large datasets. If the data doesn't need to be live, another option would be to create a procedure that caches the joined data in a table on a schedule and then use that table in the report. If those options aren't adequate, you may want to look at using a different reporting tool such as Excel (with web services and power query) or Tableau (if you have licenses).

Comment: Thank you for taking some time from your schedule and answering. Unfortunately there's a many-to-many relationship between my tables so I cant use `Lookup` and `LookupSet`. And the tool must be SSRS since it is deployed in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: SSRS just isn't the right tool for this job. It can do aggregation, but beyond that it's not a data transformation tool. You'll need to find another tool to do the merge before you pass the data to SSRS. If you have a SQL Server instance that SharePoint can access, that would be a good option. If you have no database available to you, that's not a great reporting environment to begin with.